# How to save the result of grep to variable x?

Tags: bash, grep

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.pdf; do

    echo $i
    x= pdfinfo "$i" | grep "Title" # nothing is stored in variable x
    echo $x

    if [ ! -z $x ]; then
        echo $x # print null
        cp $i "$x"
    fi
done
```

Nothing is stored in variable `x` — but why not and how do I do it.

Comment: FYI: the notation you used set the environment variable `x` to an empty string and passed that to `pdfinfo` (which duly ignored it), but it was only passed (set) for that one command (not the `grep`, for example). This is occasionally very useful; it was not what you intended, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parentheses or backquotes:

```
x=$(pdfinfo "$i" | grep "Title")
```

or

```
x=`pdfinfo "$i" | grep "Title"`
```

Note that the latter solution should be avoided now, it is the historical way of doing it and is replaced by `$(...)`. The `$(...)` solution is more readable in particular in case of nested substitutions.

Comment: Yes, but the order of preference should be `$(...)` before using back-quotes. You need to know back-quotes for backwards compatibility; you should only use `$(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
x=`pdfinfo "$i" | grep "Title"`
```

Comment: You should not use back tics, its old and obsoleted. Use parentheses `$(code)`.